# Hash table with linear probing

Tags: c

I am writing a hash table with linear probing, but my program has a mistake. My task is writing the number of occurrences of each word in a text. For example, my file contains these words:

```
lol lol lol a c d
```

The output is:

```
lol = 3, a = 1, c = 1, d = 2.
```

(But `d` should not be 2!)  It happens when SIZE_OF_TABLE is 10. And when the SIZE_OF_TABLE is 2 the program doesn't work. True result must be:

```
lol = 3, a = 1, c = 1, d = 1.
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX 10  
#define SIZE_OF_TABLE 10
#define MAX_STRING 256
#define THAT_OCCUP 0

struct HT{
    int amount;
    int occup;//occupancy   
    char string[MAX_STRING];
};

unsigned int long hash(const char *str);
struct HT* init(int size);
struct HT* reHT(struct HT* table,int* size,char* word, int* occup);
struct HT* put(struct HT* table,char* word, int* size,int* occup);
int take(struct HT* table,char* word, int* size);



unsigned int long hash(const char *str) // hash function
{
    int long hash = 5381;
    int c = 0;

    while (c == *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}

struct HT* init(int size) // create a hash table
{
    struct HT* table = (struct HT*)calloc(sizeof(struct HT*),size);
    int i = 0;

    if (size < 1)
        return NULL;

    if(NULL == table)
        return  NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        table[i].amount = 0;
        table[i].occup = 1;
    }

    return table;
}
struct HT* reHT(struct HT* table,int* size,char* word, int* occup) //rehash
{
    assert(table);
    assert(word);
    assert(size);
    assert(occup);

    table = (struct HT*)calloc(sizeof(struct HT*),(*size)*MAX);
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < (*size)/MAX)
    {   
        table = put(table, table[i].string, size, occup);
        i++;
    }
    return table;
}

struct HT* put(struct HT* table,char* word, int* size,int* occup)
{
    assert(table);
    assert(word);
    assert(size);
    assert(occup);

    int i = 0;

    i = hash(word) % (*size);

    if ((*occup) > ((*size) / 2))
        table = reHT(table, size, word, occup);


    if(1 == table[i].occup ) // if free put it
    {
        strcpy(table[i].string,word);
        table[i].amount++;
        table[i].occup = -1;
        (*occup)++;
    }

    else if (-1 == table[i].occup && strstr(table[i].string,word)) // if place isnt free and it is a similar world  just increase amount
        table[i].amount++;

    else if (-1 == table[i].occup && !strstr(table[i].string,word)) // if place isnt free and  it the words arent similar then use linear probing
    {
        i++;
        while(1)
        {
            i = (i + 1) % (*size);
            if(table[i].occup == 1)
            {
                strcpy(table[i].string,word);
                table[i].amount++;
                table[i].occup = -1;
                (*occup)++;
                break;
            }
            else if ( -1 == table[i].occup && strstr(table[i].string,word))
            {
                table[i].amount++;
                break;
            }
        }

        i = 0; // go to start and do the same thing

        while(1)
        {
            if(1 == table[i].occup)
            {
                strcpy(table[i].string,word);
                table[i].amount++;
                table[i].occup = -1;
                (*occup)++;
                break;
            }

            else if (strstr(table[i].string,word) && table[i].occup == -1)
            {
                table[i].amount++;
                break;
            }

            i++;
        }
    }

    return table;
}


int take(struct HT* table,char* word, int* size) // take amount
{
    assert(size);
    assert(word);
    assert(table);

    int i = 0;

    i = hash(word) % (*size);

    while( i < (*size))
    {
        if(strstr(table[i].string, word))
            return table[i].amount;
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;

    while( i < (*size))
    {
        if(strstr(table[i].string, word))
            return table[i].amount;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* file = fopen("text.txt","r");
    struct HT* table = NULL;
    char string[256] = {0};

    int size = SIZE_OF_TABLE;
    int occup = THAT_OCCUP;

    if (NULL == file)
        return -1;

    table = init(size); //create hash

    if ( NULL == table)
        return - 1;

    while(1 == fscanf(file, "%s", string)) // put words to hash table
    {
        table = put(table,string,&size,&occup);
    }

    printf("HASH_TABLE IS READY!!!!11111\n");
    printf("Enter WORDS!!!1111\n");

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s",string);
        if(strstr(string,"END")) // if you want to stop just enter "END"
            break;
        printf(" KOLI4ESTVO!! = %d\n", take(table, string, &size)); 
    }

    free(table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So... [debug your code](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 1):

When I compiled your code first time, I only got two warnings — that `argc` and `argv` to `main()` were unused.  That is well done — few programs presented on SO compile that cleanly.

I created a file `text.txt` containing:

```
lol
abracadabra
a
a
d
d
d
a
d
c
```

When I ran the program, instrumented enough to print some information as it goes (and modified to terminate cleanly on EOF), I got:

```
$ ./ht
Adding [lol]
Adding [abracadabra]
Adding [a]
Adding [a]
Adding [d]
Adding [d]
Adding [d]
Adding [a]
Adding [d]
Adding [c]
HASH_TABLE IS READY!!!!11111
Enter WORDS!!!1111
c
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [c] = 9
d
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [d] = 9
a
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [a] = 9
lol
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [lol] = 1
abracadabra
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [abracadabra] = 9
$
```

That's odd; I didn't create that many entries of any single word.  When run under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), there are many problems:

```
==98849== Invalid write of size 4
==98849==    at 0x100001173: init (ht.c:49)
==98849==    by 0x1000019A9: main (ht.c:188)
==98849==  Address 0x10080b588 is 120 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 2,736 in arena "client"
==98849== 
==98849== Invalid write of size 4
==98849==    at 0x100001180: init (ht.c:50)
==98849==    by 0x1000019A9: main (ht.c:188)
==98849==  Address 0x10080b58c is 124 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 2,736 in arena "client"
==98849== 
Adding [lol]
==98849== Invalid read of size 4
==98849==    at 0x1000015C9: put (ht.c:89)
==98849==    by 0x1000019F1: main (ht.c:196)
==98849==  Address 0x10080b58c is 124 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 2,736 in arena "client"
==98849== 
==98849== Invalid write of size 1
==98849==    at 0x1003FE3A0: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==98849==    by 0x1001B4113: strcpy (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==98849==    by 0x10000175A: put (ht.c:91)
==98849==    by 0x1000019F1: main (ht.c:196)
==98849==  Address 0x10080b590 is 128 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 2,736 in arena "client"
==98849== 
==98849== Invalid write of size 4
==98849==    at 0x10000175B: put (ht.c:93)
==98849==    by 0x1000019F1: main (ht.c:196)
==98849==  Address 0x10080b58c is 124 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 2,736 in arena "client"
==98849== 
…and a whole lot more in a similar vein…
```

A quick look at `init()` shows some of the problem:

```
struct HT* init(int size) // create a hash table
{
    struct HT* table = (struct HT*)calloc(sizeof(struct HT*),size);
    int i = 0;

    if (size < 1)
        return NULL;

    if(NULL == table)
        return  NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        table[i].amount = 0;
        table[i].occup = 1;
    }
```

You've allocated an array of `size` pointers, but you try to use them as if you've allocated an array of `size` entries of `struct HT`.

At minimum, you need to write:

```
    struct HT *table = (struct HT *)calloc(sizeof(*table), size);
```

This allocates an array of structures instead of an array of pointers.

Fixing that removes the `valgrind` errors.  The output is still not correct, though:

```
$ ./ht
Adding [lol]
Adding [abracadabra]
Adding [a]
Adding [a]
Adding [d]
Adding [d]
Adding [d]
Adding [a]
Adding [d]
Adding [c]
HASH_TABLE IS READY!!!!11111
Enter WORDS!!!1111
a
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [a] = 9
lol
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [lol] = 1
abracadabra
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [abracadabra] = 9
b
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [b] = 9
c
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [c] = 9
d
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [d] = 9
e
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [e] = 0
antimony
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [antimony] = 0
$
```

I think I have established that the 9 is not a coincidence given that there are 10 lines in the data file.  When I reduced the data to 6 lines, with just `a` repeated, and the output was:

```
$ ./ht
Adding [lol]
Adding [abracadabra]
Adding [a]
Adding [d]
Adding [a]
Adding [c]
HASH_TABLE IS READY!!!!11111
Enter WORDS!!!1111
a
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [a] = 5
d
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [d] = 5
c
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [c] = 5
abracadabra
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [abracadabra] = 5
lol
 KOLI4ESTVO!! [lol] = 1
$
```

I also tried a lot of lines (15) with a number of repeats, and the program crashed.  I think the numerology should give you some hints.  I'd not be surprised to find that the code that rebuilds the hash table has similar size bugs to the one in `init()`.

I think you need to create yourself a function that can print the details about and contents of the hash table so that you can use that to see what is being created.